# Accesing variable from a different class in java

Tags: java

Is there a way i can pass a variable from one class with main to another one with main method.
For example

```
class A
{

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {

         int num = 5;
    }
}

class B
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
    }
}
```

Is there a way Class B can access int num from class A without getting null value?

Answer (score 1):

`num` is a variable with scope only in the `main()` method. It effectively disappears once the method finishes up. This is true even considering that `main()` is static.

You can do this however:

```
class A {
    public int num = 5;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}

class B {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new A().num);     // should print '5'
    }
}
```

Notice that you need to create a new instance of `A` in order to access `num`, since `num` is an element of the object `A`.

Comment: It would be worth explaining how to make a variable scoped to the class, and how to make or prevent its accessibilty.

Comment: Heh. I must have posted just before you submitted your edit.  Well, you already had my upvote ;-)